# Check if multiple sub lists are present in a source list

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq, dynamic-programming

I have two classes defined as :

```
public class MyclassSource
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Value { get; set; }

            public MyclassSource(string x, string y)
            {
                Name = x;
                Value = y;
            }
        }

public class MyclassTarget
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Value { get; set; }
        }
```

I have created a list of MyclassSource as follows

```
List<MyclassSource> SourceList = new List<MyclassSource>
            {
               new MyclassSource("T1","V1"),
               new MyclassSource("T3","V3"),
               new MyclassSource("T4","V4"),
               new MyclassSource("T7","V7"),
               new MyclassSource("T8","V8"),
            };
```

A dictionary let's call it Mapper declared as:

```
        List<string> s1 = new List<string> {"T1", "T5"};
        List<string> s2 = new List<string> {"T4", "T6"};
        List<string> s3 = new List<string> {"T3", "T2"};
        List<string> s4 = new List<string> { "T4", "T7" };

        Dictionary<string, List<string>> Mapper = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
        {
            {"X1", s1}, {"X2", s2}, {"X3", s3}, {"X4", s4}
        };
```

for each key in dictionary Mapper i.e. x1, x2, x3, x4 there are possible list string values:
for X1 , list of value is s1 as such  possible values are T1, T5 and so on

These values can be present in Sourcelist. we need to identify if the possible string value from dictionary for each key is present in the sourcelist and if present, then fetch the corresponding value. The fetch should happen only if a single match is found, if both the value say T4, T7 are in source list then throw excpetion..

I have tried some code but unable to fetch as expected. secondly, I was thinking if it's possible to avoid two for loops

```
    foreach (var item in Mapper)
         {
                MyclassTarget t = new MyclassTarget {Name = item.Key};               
    
                foreach (var value in item.Value)
                {
                    if (SourceList.Select(x => x.Name).Contains(value))
                    {
                        t.Value =  // assing the value somehow if unique match found.
                    }
                }
        }
```

Expected Result would be
MyClassTarget object being assigned following values as we iterate over the for loop above

```
        Name        value
obj1    X1           V1
obj2    X2           V4
Obj3    X3           V3
Obj4    Exceptions as more than one value matches
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
foreach (var item in Mapper)
{
    MyclassTarget t = new MyclassTarget { Name = item.Key };
    t.Value = SourceList.Where(x => item.Value.Contains(x.Name)).Count() == 1 ? SourceList.First(y => item.Value.Contains(y.Name)).Value : "Exception";
}
```

Does this produce the desired result?

Comment: This works, Thanks. However I was wondering if we need to work on the list twice, one for checking if the count ==1, second for finding the value. Will the below one will be more efficient or both approaches are equal in terms of number of iterations over list. Using your answer
`foreach (var item in Mapper) {
                MyclassTarget t = new MyclassTarget{Name = item.Key};                
                var sources = SourceList.Where(x => item.Value.Contains(x.Name)).ToList();
                t.Value = sources.Count == 1 ? sources.First().Value : "exception";                      }`

Comment: "Caching" the SourceList.Where is probably a little bit more performant, than my solution. But I am just guessing.